# how different are meego and android stacks?

Tags: android, linux, meego

Do MeeGo and Android stacks share any relevant libraries in their userspace on top of the Linux kernel?

Looking at the Android stack, I guess MeeGo shares all the components of the Linux kernel, including:

- Display Drivers
- Flash Memory Drivers
- IPC Drivers
- USB Drivers
- Keypad Drivers
- Audio Drivers
- Power Management

How about:

- WiFi Drivers
- Camera Drivers
- Bluetooth Drivers

I have read from CyanogenMod that most complains when trying to have CM running on wonky devices seems to be WiFi, Camera and Bluetooth. Does this mean that this is an Android-specific part not shared by MeeGo, which is otherwise another Linux-based platform?

How about the other parts of the Android Stack? I am guessing all the Application Framework parts are Android Specific, and also most of the Libraries, like Media Framework and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Android employs their Dalvik virtual machine, with application code
  compiled from Java. A Native Development Kit (NDK) is also offered
  for high-performance applications  that must use C++, such as games.
- The MeeGo operating system is primarily based on Nokia's Qt platform 
  and the Qt Creator, with applications written in C++.
- Android's focus has been on porting to the ARM-based CPUs that 
  dominate mobile devices.
- In Android, every built-in application can be replaced. In MeeGo,
  developers are prohibited from doing so.
- MeeGo is designed to prohibit fragmentation and ensure application
  compatibility to any MeeGo-based device.

More here : http://www.eedailynews.com/2010/05/android-vs-meego-two-approaches-to.html